# Efficient determination of which strings in an array are substrings of the others?

Tags: c#, algorithm, string

In C#, Say you have an array of strings, which contain only characters '0' and '1':

```
string[] input = { "0101", "101", "11", "010101011" };
```

And you'd like to build a function:

```
public void IdentifySubstrings(string[] input) { ... }
```

That will produce the following:

```
"0101 is a substring of 010101011"
"101 is a substring of 0101"
"101 is a substring of 010101011"
"11 is a substring of 010101011"
```

And you are **NOT** able to use built-in string functionality (such as String.Substring).

How would one efficiently solve this problem? Of course you could plow through it via brute force, but it just feels like there ought to be a way to accomplish it with a tree (since the only values are 0's and 1's, it feels like a binary tree ought to fit somehow). I've read a little bit about things like suffix trees, but I'm uncertain if that's the right path to be going down.

Any efficient solutions you can think of?

Comment: Or maybe a job interview question? In fact, this feels just like a question I often ask people to answer before they come in due to the "you are NOT able to use built-in string functionality" portion.

Comment: @Oded - No. 
@Tim C - Yes, it is commonly used in job interview questions.

Comment: Is that why you are asking it though? I don't mean to offend really, but I don't like to answer job interview questions. And if it is not for a job interview, can you explain why you don't want to use built in functions which have been tweaked and optimized for this purpose?

Comment: Why aren't we allowed to use the built-in functionality? Is this a real problem or just some test? Are there any other things that we aren't allowed to use, or will you only tell us the remaining restrictions after we've spent time creating an answer?

Comment: Yes, as I stated it is commonly used for job interview questions. That is why I'm asking it, because I'm only familiar with the brute-force method of solving it, and I'd like input. If you don't want to answer, then you don't have to, there's plenty of other questions on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Mark Byers - No other restrictions, not some bizarre test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You have no choice but each byte (or bit ;-) in the searched string at least once. Probably best to leave them as bytes. Then implement a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (or variant). Load all substrings into the trie. The node objects should contain members identifiying which to of the loaded array elements they belong. Then search it with each substring and make your matches.

Comment: Would the performance gain over the brute force method here be simply that once you reach a leaf node you can be assured that your test string is not a substring of any of the others?

Comment: More thought about this answer:  I think this will work and be quite efficient, but I don't think it will identify substrings that begin at positions other than 0. For example, I don't think it will identify "101" as being a substring of "0101".

Comment: That is right, you would have to vary the use of trie. A quick way - for example, add to it every substring starting form 2nd byte on out, too. of course this drops you right away to o(n^2) so you'd have to have a savvier variant than that. Tough problem, good luck.

Comment: Heh, well, I'll vote you up and accept the answer anyway, since it's likeliest to be as good a starting spot as I'll get.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but's it's close

```
var string2FindLen = string2Find.Length;
var ndx = 0;
var x = string2Find[ndx];
foreach(var c in string2LookIn)
{
    if (ndx == string2FindLen) return true;
    if (c==x) x = string2Find[++ndx];
    else ndx = 0;
}
return false;
```

Comment: You may have misunderstood the question; your solution only operates to see if one string is a substring of another, not N strings in N strings.